# What is the name of the statistical paradox / law that says optimizing the metric may not lead to optimal outcome

Tags: optimization, paradox

I am trying remember to the name of the statistical paradox / law name that effectively says that optimizing the metric may not lead to the optimal outcome. As far as I can recall, this paradox / law has been used in portfolio management as well as A / B testing.

Also, its not the Yule-Simpson paradox

Comment: Are you asking about overfitting?

Comment: its not exactly overfitting. its more about if you fit against a metric instead of the actual outcome for example, A/B tests gives sub-optimal results. Or lets say in portfolio management, we can chose weaker individual assets to get a better portfolio

Answer (score 3):

Goodhart's Law? "When a measure becomes a target, it ceases to be a good measure." It started in macroeconomics, but has been extended to many realms.

Also in the area of macroeconomic policy, the so-called Lucas Critique has some similar features.

A similar one in social psychology is Campbell's law: "The more any quantitative social indicator is used for social decision-making, the more subject it will be to corruption pressures and the more apt it will be to distort and corrupt the social processes it is intended to monitor."

Theers's also "the cobra effect": attempted solution to a problem makes the problem worse.